# What better to use Forwarding or Redirecting?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

In my webpage I have a "Login" form that sending values to "myServlet". "myServlet" makes connection to DB and after that if "flag" is positive I want to show "user.jsp" with appropriate user data, else to show "error.jsp". What is the better way to display this pages using ServletConfig().....forward(req, res) or response.redirect()? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep this redirection transparent to user, then you better use request forwarding. When you forward a request it will simply transfer the execution to the target jsp file. But when you redirect it, client will be notified about this and then it will again have to send a new request to the target jsp. So in the second case there is a performance penalty being occurred. Request forwarding has an added advantage in this case.

The redirection also has an advantage. When you redirect a request, clients will be aware of it. So users will be able to bookmark this url and will be able to access it in the future directly. It is a nice feature if you take care of the security issues i.e., preventing access if not logged in etc.

What you want to do now is up to you and your requirements.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When we use *forwarding* mechanism the source Servlet program directly contacts to Destination Servlet/Jsp/Web resource program ,in *Redirection* mechanism source servlet takes a round trip with browser window to contact with destination Servlet/jsp/web resource program.

so forwarding mechanism is faster than sendRedirection,more over in sendRedirection the request url will be changed,example:www.sun.com(for java) gives us www.oracle.com.

within the application go for forwarding mechanism..may be you can understand this.